# White space after string input

Tags: c++, whitespace

Suppose i want to input "Wrong input" string into the following code :

```
cin >> name;
```

The result would be only "Wrong" while the "input" would be neglected.

I know that this kind of situation marked as "white space", but why does it happens? why the compiler cant input the whole string as it is, referring the white space as a "_" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler does what the C++ language specification requires it to, and the language specification requires things that people often need.  Sure, wanting to read across whitespace is common too; there's another way to achieve that:

```
getline(std::cin, name)
```

Which reads until the end of the line.  [`getline` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will tell you that you can terminate when you reach another specific character if you want to - just add that character as a third argument.

If you want to change whitespace to `'_'`, you can find and replace instances of whitespace in the `std::string` `name` after reading.  Use `std::string::find`, `std::isspace` and `std::string::operator[]` - all of which are documented at cppreference.com.

Answer (score 1):

The input **"Wrong input"** first goes into the buffer of the program and on seeing a white space after **"Wrong"** it simply pushes the value to the variable **name**,thereby ignoring the second part "input" of your input.It happens because **cin** sees the whitespace as a newline character.

You can use one of the following methods to do it:

1.using getline function

```
    getline( std::cin, name );
```

2.using cin.get function

```
    cin.get(cin, name);
```

What these function do is they ignore white space.